# Android Twitter integration failed even using latest Twitter 4J 3.0.3

Tags: android, twitter, integration, social-networking

Hi i'm using this [Project](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidTwitter). And i have replace old Twitter4j with the latest version (3.0.3).

I also changed from

```
   mHttpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token", "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
```

to

```
  mHttpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token","https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
```

I'm getting this error. Please help me thanks.

**Errors:**

```
11-28 11:33:44.574: W/System.err(334): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
11-28 11:33:44.583: W/System.err(334):  at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
11-28 11:33:44.583: W/System.err(334):  at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
11-28 11:33:44.583: W/System.err(334):  at com.twitter.android.TwitterApp$2.run(TwitterApp.java:126)
11-28 11:33:44.583: W/System.err(334): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
11-28 11:33:44.583: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)
11-28 11:33:44.583: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:253)
11-28 11:33:44.583: W/System.err(334):  at oauth.signpost.basic.HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.getContent(HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.java:18)
11-28 11:33:44.594: W/System.err(334):  at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.handleUnexpectedResponse(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:228)
11-28 11:33:44.594: W/System.err(334):  at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:189)
11-28 11:33:44.594: W/System.err(334):  ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, current version of API is 1.1.

All the URLs you have used are deprecated and one example of correct path is:

For example:

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
```

Comment: Hi Paresh this what i'm currently using mHttpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token","https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");  Why its not working?

Comment: hi murali, u got any solution for your problem. i am also facing same issue. please update answer. thanks